# Cors Issue with Angular app which is using Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, cors

We have an Angular 13 project and a web API Core project. We are using Azure AD authentication. We are using MSAL for Azure AD auth.

When we run the Font end app locally and try to hit one end point from on Web APIs(running locally), we get the response without any issues.

But when the same code is deployed on Azure and we test the same functionality, we are getting the following error:-

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.dev.site.io/portal/api/case
from origin 'https://portal.dev.site.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

When we run Front end locally but try to hit the web api on Azure we get the same issue.

We are looking into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/331989/azure-ad-cors-issue.html

Ant inputs would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must not be passed in the _request_ but in the _response_.

Comment: CORS has nothing do do with authentication and Azure AD. In CORS, the server tells the browser what URLs can be called. CORS works the same even with anonymous authentication. The error is clear anyway - your browser tried to access a URL in a *different domain*. You'll have to modify your *web app* and add the API's URL to the permitted CORS URLs

Comment: @Heiko you are corrected. We have already removed and I forgot to update the text. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I agree to you that CORs is not related to Azure AD. I just wanted to share how things are setup for us on Azure and what we are using.

Comment: The authentication method has nothing to do with CORS though. The *server* has to add the CORS headers in the response. What server are you using? You need to configure it to add the API url to the allowed sites. Right now the only information is the error message which includes the SPA and API URLs

Comment: @Panagiotis, back end is written in web api core. your text "You'll have to modify your web app and add the API's URL to the permitted CORS URLs" is not clear to me. Could you please explain what do u mean by that?

Comment: @Panagiotis, we are using "appService" for Front end. We are not using "*" anywhere. We have configured CORS on Web api core side also.

Comment: Have you checked [Tutorial: Host a RESTful API with CORS in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api) ?

Answer (score -1):

In you core API, add this code inside the `Configure` method.

```
     app.UseCors(corsOptions =>
       {/*
         corsOptions.AllowAnyOrigin();
         corsOptions.AllowAnyMethod();*/
     });
```

Keep in mind that this will allow requests from any origin and can run into security issues. So you'd better know the origin of your client app so can set it like this

```
  app.UseCors(corsOptions =>
     {
      corsOptions.WithOrigins("example.com/clientapp");
      corsOptions.WithMethods("GET", "POST");
     });
```

this will allow only GET and POST methods from your client application domain.

Comment: We have already done this configuration for Web Api Core.

Comment: `example.com/clientapp` is _not_ a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), though.

Comment: It's because stack overflow complaints about the full domain I put `example.com` to let it pass

Comment: @jub0bs, we have done correct configuration for sure.

Comment: Seems this would be even easier to use.

https://geekshangout.com/azure-app-service-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present/

Comment: Additional Info

There is a facility on Azure Portal to test the API's and we have found some issues there.

Comment: We have found the issue on Azure Portal...I will post the solution..in some time...There is way to test your api on Azure Portal..